Does the Space of Functions have a Compact Covering?
Let $X$ be an arbitrary set and $\mathbb{R}^X$ denote the set of real valued functions on $X$. Define the metric $$d(f,g) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i \wedge \sup_{x \in X} |f(x) - g(x)|}{2^i}$$ on $\mathbb{R}^X$. Is it true that $\mathbb{R}^X$ has a compact covering? i.e. a collection of compact subsets $K_n$ such that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty K_n = \mathbb{R}^X$?
I feel like the answer should be no, since for the real numbers one uses sets analogous to $\{f \in \mathbb{R}^X: d(f,0) \leq n\}$ and I cannot verify compactness of these sets. Any help would be massively appreciated!

What does $\wedge$ mean here?

I mean $x \wedge y \equiv \min(x,y)$

I'll assume that by "collection of compact subsets" you mean a countable collection (otherwise every space would be covered by its singletons). In that case the answer to your question is:
No. $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ does not have a compact covering.
Proof: For every $r \in \mathbb{R}$, define $\chi_r(x)$ to be the indicator function of $\{r\}$, ie the function that has the value $1$ on $r$ and $0$ elsewhere. Note that, for the metric you define, we then have that
$$
\forall r \neq r' \in \mathbb{R}, d(\chi_r, \chi_{r'}) = 1.
$$
Now we prove the following claim:
Claim: Let $N$ be any subset of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ that contains infinitely many distinct $\chi_r$. Then N is not compact.
Proof of claim: Let $R$ be the set of $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\chi_r \in N$, and consider the set of open balls
$$
B := \{B_\frac{1}{2}(\chi_r) : r \in R\}.
$$
Note that the balls in $B$ are disjoint, since the distance between any two $\chi_r$ is $1$. In particular, each $\chi_r$ is contained in at most one element of $B$. Let
$$
C \subset \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} : d(x,\chi_r) \geq \frac{1}{4} \forall r \in R\}
$$
$C$ is open (proof left as an exercise), so $B \cup \{C\}$ is an open cover of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, and thus an open cover of $N$. But each element of $\{\chi_r : r \in R\}$ is contained in a unique element of this cover. Thus any finite subset of this open cover can only cover finitely many of these $\chi_r$, and thus does not cover $N$. This proves that $N$ is not compact.
Now we are ready to prove that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ does not have a compact covering:
Suppose $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ has a compact covering. By the above claim, each compact set in this covering can only contain a finite number of the $\chi_r$. Since there are only countably many sets in this covering, it implies that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ has only countably many $\chi_r$, contradicting the fact that the real numbers are uncountable.
